# How can I rewrite this?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Can you explain how mod_rewrite works using this as an example:

```
http://www.domain.com/page.php?q=keyword1,keyword2,keywordn&page=x&param=i
=>
http://www.domain.com/page/keyword1,keyword2,keywordn?page=x&param=i
```

Where `n`, `x`, & `i` may be any integer.

The purpose is twofold here:

- I need the appropriate solution to that specific example and
- I want to learn how it was done.

I am using Apache.

Comment: Start here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/ ; especially this link: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use
Rewriterule ^/page/([A-Za-z]+[0-9]+[,])+$ page.php?q=$1 [L]

The rest will be appended automatically.

Comment: thanks perfrect for validation and just got it working by editing it a little thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Rewriterule ^/page\.php\?q=([A-Za-z0-9,]+)&(.*)$ /page/$1?$2 [L]
```

as for explanation:

we match url with regexp and use matched elements inside () as variables $1 $2 later